# What are the usage scenarios of state holder class VS event in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know when to use state holder class and when to use trigger event?

`event`

```
@Composable
fun ClickCounter(clicks: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text("I've been clicked $clicks times")
    }
}
```

use `state holder class`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClickCounter1(state: State) {
  Button(onClick = {
    state.onClick()
  }) {
    Text("I've been clicked ${state.clicks} times")
  }
}


class State(
  var clicks: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)
) {

  fun onClick() {
    clicks.value = clicks.value + 1
  }

}
```

I'm a beginner and it seems to me that both ways will work.

So what are the different applicable scenarios of these two ways?